# Cognos Report Studio VS Tableau Desktop (HTML TAGS)

Tags: jquery, html, tableau-api, cognos

So I am currently using Cognos Report Studio 10.2.2 and I don't know much about Tableau. I have looked online but there is one thing that I want to know more about and I can't find anything on it. In Cognos I can drag over an HTML tag and create custom JS/Jquery or HTML and CSS in them and add more of a custom feel to my reports. Is there something similar in Tableau that I can do to make reports more customizable like I do in Cognos? Right now in Cognos I have created a sliding suite of reports with a custom search engine but I couldn't find anything like this in Tableau. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Tableau Desktop and Tableau Server are two different products. I suggest downloading a trail http://www.tableau.com/products/trial?os=windows if you're unfamiliar with the product and play around with it. You can trial both Desktop and Server.

Desktop does not have any JS/HTML/CSS functionality. Tableau Server does have a JS API http://www.tableau.com/new-features/javascript-api but it is used as functionality not appearance changes. The aesthetics of your report is controlled by Desktop.